# combine (join) objects in array javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In `d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, data)` instruction

d3.csv is a helper that uses d3.csv.parse internally to parse CSV
data loaded from a file into an array of objects, and then it passes this
to a callback.

**So data is a callback variable that holds an array of objects**

In the picture the structure of data [image: data]

You can see that the headers of the original CSV have been used as the **property names** for the **data objects**.Using d3.csv in this manner requires that your CSV file has a header row.

data is array of objects

```
data (in orange) is a combination of :
- columns array (in red) holding csv headers that means **property names** 
  for the **data objects**
- an array of 6131 elements (in green) holding the values associated with 
  these propertie
```

Now that we have finished describing the desired structure:

Imagine I have an array of 6131 elements (the same as described in the 
 picture in green)

```
var dataArray =[];
 for(var i=0;i<6131;i++){
        ddd[i]={x:..,y:...etc};
        dataArray.push(ddd[i]); 
 }
```

My question is how to construct in reverse the same identical structure described before and result with the same data like the one got from d3.csv.

```
var columnsArray=["NOM","PRENOM","SPECIALITE","Full_Address","VILLE","lat","lon"];
```

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a `columns` property to your `dataArray` object:

```
dataArray.columns = columnsArray;
```

Comment: I put here your first answer :  because I tested and worked perfectly by adding   var desiredArray = d3.csvParse(csv);  like the following

Comment: function toCSV(row) {
         
      return columnsArray.map(column => row[column]).join(',');
           }
     var columnsArray= ["NOM","PRENOM","SPECIALITE","Full_Address","VILLE","lat","lon"];
           const header = columnsArray.join(',');
           const rows = mydataArray.map(toCSV).join('\n');
           const csv = header + '\n' + rows;  var desiredArray = d3.csvParse(csv); please add it as first option in your answer. Thanks Wex !! Fast and great responses as usual, can't thank you enough for putting up with the newbie questions :). Cheers